# Multiple servers in connection string(web.config)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

Is there a way i can mention multiple servers in connection string of my web.config file provided they are having same credentials. In case if my one server goes down or any thing happens wrong it can automatically switch to another server.

Regards,
Riz

Answer (score 0):

You have to add multiple connectionStrings

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="connectionOne" connectionString="Data Source=yourServerName;Initial   
      Catalog=yourDataBaseName;User ID=(PutYourCredentialsNameHere);Password= (yourPassword)"   
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     <add name="connectionTwo" connectionString="Data Source=yourServerName;Initial   
    Catalog=yourDataBaseName;User ID=(PutYourCredentialsNameHere);Password=(yourPassword)" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zey's answer is correct in that you can have multiple connection strings in the web config. However there is nothing 'automatic' about this in case of failure. You'll need to implement this auto-switch over in code.

However, this isn't the most robust solution. It would be better to handle this on the database layer by combinations of clustering and mirroring. You haven't mentioned what database this is but for example SQL 2012 has introduced the concept of [AlwaysOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx) availability groups.

Ultimately though most of the decisions come down to cost and the level of availability you are trying to achieve i.e. it's far cheaper to just perform a manual failover at the risk of increased downtime. Of course it's not just the database you need to worry about, it's the switch, the firewall, the actual server...

Managed cloud services like [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) are looking pretty attractive these days!